# Assign Multiple Filter to Single FilterGroup in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, filter, custom-attributes, search-criteria

I am working on to **get product from custom attributes using search criteria**. i need  to **assign multiple filter to single filter group**.

**what i did:**

**$cus Query:**

```
{"area":["320","321","322"],"city":"342","size":""}
```

**My code to get a product:**

```
           foreach($cusQuery as $key => $value)
            {

      // create multiple filter for single attribute based on  multiselect(advanced search):

                $filter= '';

                echo $key ."\n";
                if($key =='city' || 'area')
                {
                    if(is_array($value))
                    {
                        foreach($value as $siglevalue)
                        {

                            $filter[$filter_loop] = $this->_filterBuilder->create()->setField($key)->setConditionType('finset')->setValue($siglevalue);
                            $filter_loop++;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(strlen($value) != 0) {
                            $filter[$filter_loop] = $this->_filterBuilder->create()->setField($key)->setConditionType('finset')->setValue($value);
                        }
                    }

//create filter Group:

                   if(!empty($filter))
                   {
                       foreach($filter as $fil)
                       {

                           $filter_group[$filter_group_loop] = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($fil)->create();
                           $filter_group_loop++;
                       }
                   }

                }
                $filter_loop++;
            }

            $search_criteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->create()->setFilterGroups($filter_group);
            $productdata = $this->_productModelRepository->getList($search_criteria)->getItems();  
            echo "Product Count" .count($productdata);
```

I know following way to  **assign multi-filter to single filter group**:

```
 $filter_group = $this->_filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter[0])
            ->addFilter($filter[1])
            ->addFilter($filter[2])
            ->addFilter($filter[4])
            ->create();
```

But, I have filters in **array**  so, i can't choose these way.

Suggest me, How to assign multiple filter in single filter group for my way or any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I find out the `\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder` have **setFilters** function to give array of multiple filters.

so, i change my code

```
foreach($filter as $fil)
     {
           $this->_logger->addDebug("array filter group  loop" ."\n");
           $filter_group[$filter_group_loop] = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($fil)->create();    //->addFilter($fil)->create();
           $filter_group_loop++;
       }
```

to :

```
$filter_group[$filter_group_loop] = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->setFilters($filter)->create();    //->addFilter($fil)->create();
```

Now, create Multiple Filters to Single Filter Group.